# Print per 2 char in java arraylist (non static arraylist)

Tags: java, arraylist

Im new with java. im getting struggle with printin something, this is my arraylist

```
arraylist = ['a','u','o','e']
```

If my arraylist isnt a static length arraylist. How could I print that list into this

"Your Value: au, oe"

Im kinda confused

Thanks for advance

Comment: those are `arraylist.get(0)`, `arraylist.get(1)` and `arraylist.get(2)`, `arraylist.get(3)`. What is it that confuses you?

Comment: So the print statement would be system.out.prntln("your value: " + arraylist.get(1) + arraylist.get(2) + arraylist.get(3)); ?

Comment: @Glaciers no, that would print "Your Value: uoe".

Comment: @Glaciers close. You're missing the first one (`arraylist.get(0)`) and `", "` between "u" and "o".

Comment: What if the length of array isnt static?  Im sorry Im newbie in programming things

Comment: @Glaciers that's not the problem as you stated it. You said you had an ArrayList with four elements. If you have a different problem please [edit] your question with the exact problem you're having.

Comment: I did edit the question, thx for advice

Comment: This does not look like Java - are you confusing Java and Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply loop the array and print each character, and when `(index +1) % 2 == 0 && i != list.size() -1`, which means it is the 2rd,4th,6th,... element and not the last one, print an extra `,`.

```java
  public void printArray() {
        List<Character> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList('a', 'u', 'o', 'e'));
        System.out.print("Your Value: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(list.get(i));
            if ((i + 1) % 2 == 0 && i != list.size() - 1) {
                System.out.print(",");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is work , thank you very much and Im sorry if someone couldnt understand what Im asking about

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate String with character "+" like this.

```
System.out.println("Your Value: " + arraylist.get(0) + arraylist.get(1) + ", " + arraylist.get(2) + arraylist.get(3));
```

or you can use a smarter way, using static method inside String class called "format" like this:

```
System.out.println(String.format("Your Value: %s%s, %s%s", arraylist.get(0), arraylist.get(1), arraylist.get(2), arraylist.get(3)));
```

You can learn more about String.format() reading this post:

https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-format

Comment: fabio19933, while this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

So an array is a datatype that we use to store multiple values in a single variable. Arrays start at index 0 rather than 1. So this means the first element in the array has an index of 0

```
array = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
```

So, for your example we would want to do this:

```
System.out.println("Your Value: " + arrayList.get(0) + arrayList.get(1) + "," + arrayList.get(2) + arrayList.get(3)
```

Where we say `arrayList.get(0)` that is accessing the first letter in the array which is 'a'

Comment: Appreciate your answer, what if the array is expandable?

Comment: What do you mean by expandable? Do you mean if the array is constantly growing? Or do you mean an `ArrayList<Integer`. Please explain a little more and I will try and help